# Grub bootloader missing

Tags: 16.04, grub2, windows-10, bootloader

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed on my system. My grub bootloader is all of sudden missing and I am directly logging in Windows 10 without getting an option to choose between Ubuntu and Windows 10. What should I do? I tried this `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`, but it is not working.

Comment: @karel I saw this fix but do I have to create an Ubuntu bootable pendrive?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a bootable Ubuntu USB pendrive.